# restore project from last successful build visual studio - No source control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, build, restore

I know I should have used source control and I'm an idiot for not doing it so we can leave that out.

As the title hints I've lost all the code for my project. It all went away after a blackout, when I restarted the computer the solution was empty. However, I can still run the program from my last successful build.

I did find recent questions with the same content but the closest to an answer in my case was how to regenerate code from a .dll file and all I have is an .exe file.

Is there a way to regenerate my code from this .exe file? Maybe there is a way to reset my entire computer to before the blackout occurred?

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Telerik JustDecompiler (free, http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) can restore project from .exe

Comment: Check for files *in the solution folder* (with windows explorer).These will have been saved on a build and it is unlikely they will have been deleted.

Comment: Never mind the solution being empty, is your code still on the disk? Look in your solution directory for your source files. Then re-add them to the empty solution. It's an annoying task, especially if the project has a few hundred files, but you should be able to get it going again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to regenerate my code from this .exe file?

There are a few tools out there for decompiling application binaries such [RedGate Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) or [JetBrains dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to name but two.  These tools will decompile your applications binaries in order to obtain useful source code.

> It all went away after a blackout

Not entirely sure how the binary was able to be built and the solution was not saved.  Generally VS will save the solution during compilation.

### Windows File History

If you were lucky enough to have your source code in your **My Documents** folder (honestly most developers don't) and just happened to have **Windows File History** enabled (honestly most users don't), you may be able to recover files that were automatically backed-up.  It's shame Windows doesn't sort of prod you into enabling this by default when Windows is installed, but I digress.

### SCM

Whilst it is downloading you may want to setup SCM too.  There's lots to pick from.

Comment: I downloaded JetBrains and at least I was able to get some of the code back. Thank you for help

Comment: @Oliver Glad to hear that Oliver and you are quite welcome.  Now don't forget to look into source control. :) Subversion is a good start.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try file recovery software like [EaseUs Recovery](http://www.easeus.com/). It can recover most number of files even after disk format.

Not sure if you can recover everything but you can try to get business logic class or dlls